# Ex 14.22 Lee's Smooth Manifold: interior multiplication

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds

> **14.22: pg 362 Lee's Smooth Manifold** Let $X$ be a smooth vector field on $M$.
>
> 1. If $w$ is a smooth differential form then $i_Xw$ is smooth.
>          $$ i_X w:= (X \lrcorner w)_p =X_p \lrcorner w_p. $$
> 2. $i_X:\Omega^k(M) \rightarrow \Omega^{k-1}(M)$ is linear over $C^\infty(M)$, corresponding to a smooth bundle homomoprhism 
>          $$ i_X: \wedge ^kT^*M \rightarrow \wedge^{k-1}T^*M. $$

---

I would really appreciate nice explanations for both aprts. My solution for 1. is **ugly** (below). For 2. **how does linearity over $C^\infty(M)$ imply bundle homomorphism**?

---

My thoughts for 2. are using lemma 14.13 and working in a local coordinate chart.

> **Lemma 14.13, pg 358:**  If $w \in \wedge^k(V^*) $ and $\eta \in \wedge^l(V^*)$, 
>           $$ i_v (w \wedge \eta) = (i_v w ) \wedge \eta  + (-1)^k w \wedge (i_v \eta). $$

which I believe is what the solution wants.

---

May attempt for 1.

We work locally on a local chart $(U, (x^i))$ around  $w$. We know $w = \sum w_I dx^I$, $X=X^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} $, where $w_I, X^i$ are smooth on $U$. 
Thus, for $p \in U$, $v_2, \ldots, v_k \in T^kM$, 
\begin{align*} X_p \lrcorner w_p (v_2, \ldots, v_k) &= w_p(X_p, v_2, \ldots, v_k)  \\ 
&= \sum_I w_I(p) \sum_i X^i (p)dx^I(\frac{\partial }{\partial x^i}, v_2, \ldots, v_k) 
\end{align*}

In this form, we can see the expression is clearly representable  $\sum_{J} l_Jdx^J$ for $J$ of length $k-1$., such that $l_J$ is smooth on $U$.

---

EDIT:

Thanks for the comments below. The general theorem show that $i_X$ is then given by $i_X (v) = i_X (\tilde{v})(p)$ for some $\tilde{v} \in \Omega^k(M)$ where $\tilde{v}(p) = v$.

Comment: Your solution for 1 is fine. I wouldn't call working with coordinates ugly. In fact, in some cases, there is no other way. As for 2, it is a general (and important) fact that if $E,F\to M$ are vector bundles and $L:\Gamma(E)\to\Gamma(F)$ is linear over $C^\infty(M)$, then $L$ corresponds to a bundle morphism $E\to F$. Regardless, it follows from the definition that interior multiplication corresponds to a bundle morphism.

Comment: As @AmitaiYuval said. The second part is true by Lemma 10.29 (Bundle Homomorphism Characterization Lemma) in Lee’s.

Comment: Thanks AmitaiYuval and Sou, I understand now.  @Amitai do you want to copy/post your solution so the problem is resolved?